# How to get BLE services (i.e. Battery level, Temperatue) from cordova-plugin-ble-central?

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, intel-xdk, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have create an app using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) concept in Intel XDK, used cordova-plugin-ble-central plugin to get their info. Now o got only deviceID, RSSI value.

I am trying to Battery level,Temperature and also some related services from Beacon device using cordova plugin (https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central). But i unable connect my device.

When i run my app in device, its returns "Peripheral deviceid not found" only. My code is

```
 onConnect = function() {
            alert('onconnect start');
            // TODO check if we have the battery service
            // TODO check if the battery service can notify us
            //ble.startNotification(deviceId, battery.service,battery.level, app.onBatteryLevelChange, app.onError);
            batteryStateButton.dataset.deviceId = deviceId;
            disconnectButton.dataset.deviceId = deviceId;
            app.showDetailPage();
            alert('onconnect end');
        };    
  ble.connect(deviceId, onConnect, app.onError);
```

When i use above code, didn't get 'onconnect start' alert.
In my plugin code

```
 connect: function (device_id, success, failure) {
    alert(device_id);
    var successWrapper = function(peripheral) {
        alert('successWrapper');
        convertToNativeJS(peripheral);
        success(peripheral);
    };
    cordova.exec(successWrapper, failure, 'BLE', 'connect', [device_id]);
},
```

From plugin get device id alert only. Also i tried to pair from my mobile to device, get some error "Unable to communicate with deviceid". Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0):

Which beacon device are you working with? And do you know if the device has these services implemented?

For starters, beacons are by definition *non-connectable*, so connectivity would be an additional use case. A beacon is a Broadcaster, not a Peripheral.

A device ID and RSSI is what is expected, and this you get from advertising data, not from a GATT service.

Comment: That device name is "iBeacon" . I just tried in some playstore app (i.e., nRF Connect), it gets temperature and battery voltage also.

Comment: "iBeacon" doesn't say much, any info on manufacturer, type and so on?

Comment: Device model  [http://minew.en.alibaba.com/product/60172214312-220649015/BLE_4_0_Proximity_iBeacon_module_MiniBeacon_bluetooth_beacon_Type_Nordic_nRF51822_iBeacon.html] (http://minew.en.alibaba.com/product/60172214312-220649015/BLE_4_0_Proximity_iBeacon_module_MiniBeacon_bluetooth_beacon_Type_Nordic_nRF51822_iBeacon.html)